# Tapping on an image change the image and text in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm  trying to change the image and text on tapping of an image.
Refer to image below for more information.

[image]

Below  is the code for the xaml part.The forward and backward button should  change the image and text in orderwise means if any one continously tapp on Forward button image will change and text will also change  till the image is not over and same in case of backward button.
Xaml code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Learn_color_uwp.L_Col_Act"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Learn_color_uwp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Name="L_Col_View">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Assets/LearnColor/bg.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>        
        <Image x:Name="imgContainer"
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/ob_bg.png"              
               Height="240" Width="300"/>
        <Image x:Name="image"
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_gray_1.png"              
               Height="190" Width="290"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               />
        <Image x:Name="Header" 
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Header/_0007_header_gray.png"              
               Height="100" Width="330"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Margin="0,20,0,0"               
               />
        <Image x:Name="objName" 
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/object_name_bg.png"              
               Height="100" Width="280"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Margin="0,0,0,30"/>
        <Image x:Name="prevBtn" 
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Button/btn_previous_arrow.png"              
               Height="90" Width="100"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="60,10,0,0"
               Tapped="BckImgChng"/>
        <Image x:Name="FwdBtn"
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Button/btn_next_arrow.png"              
               Height="90" Width="100"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Margin="0,10,60,0"
               Tapped="FwdImgChng"/>
        <Image x:Name="prevObjBtn"
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Button/_0004_previous-copy-5.png"              
               Height="90" Width="80"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="80,10,0,0"/>
        <Image x:Name="fwdObjBtn"
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Button/_0005_next-copy-5.png"              
               Height="90" Width="80"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Margin="0,10,80,0"/>
        <Image x:Name="homeBtn"
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Button/btn_home.png"              
               Height="90" Width="80"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="20,140,0,0"/>
        <Image x:Name="volBtn"
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Button/btn_sound.png"              
               Height="90" Width="80"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="20,0,0,15"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Can you share your code? What is currently happening?

Comment: Currently i have just design the template xaml part and  don't know how to implement logic actually i am new to uwp platform.

Comment: Ok can you still post your design code, it will help me debug the issue, thanks!

Comment: I posted it .Have  you checked.

Answer (score 0):

The control you are looking for is a [FlipView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/flipview). You'll have to style it a bit to fit your design, but nothing that can't be done in XAML.

The ItemsTemplate is the layout of a single item:

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView1" Width="480" Height="270" 
          BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                <Image Width="480" Height="270" Stretch="UniformToFill"
                       Source="{Binding Image}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Set the ItemsSource in code behind or bind in XAML to a collection of objects holding the information of your images. E.g something like this:

```
public class MyImage
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: my requirement is diffrent Flipview doesn't help out it is not cutomizable to my requirement. Is there any other approach

Comment: I beg to differ. It might be some work to tweak the visual aspects, but nothing from your question gives me a reason why it would not be the right control. But you're free to think otherwise of course.